# роутинг web api - ошибка по сопоставления маршрутов

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Продолжаю эпопею с роутингом

Методы контроллера:

```
        public Object Get(int id)
        {
            PrivateConsultant cons = consMng.GetById(id);
            PrivateConsultantVM result = new PrivateConsultantVM
            {
                Name = cons.Name,
                Surname = cons.Surname,
                Patronymic = cons.Patronymic,
                Rating = cons.Rating,
                ServicesTitles = serviceMng.GetTitles(cons.Id)
            };
            return Ok(new { result, date = DateTime.Now });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public Object GgetByEntityId(int id)
        {
            return Ok(new { result = "GetByEntityId" });
        }
```

(2 g ввёл специально)

Настройка роутинга:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ActionRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { },
        constraints: new
        {
                action = new AlphaRouteConstraint(),
        }
    );


    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { },
        constraints: new
        {
            id = new IntRouteConstraint()
        }
    );
```

Срабатывает только этот метод метод:

```
http://localhost:54788/api/consultants/GgetByEntityId/1
```

Если так

```
http://localhost:54788/api/consultants/1
```

то ошибка

```
<Error>
<Message>Произошла ошибка.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Найдено несколько действий, соответствующих запросу: Get на типе WebApplication1.Controllers.ConsultantsController GgetByEntityId на типе WebApplication1.Controllers.ConsultantsController
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) в System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Не понимаю почему, должно работать
Когда идёт 2-й запрос, роутинг сопоставляет его с роутом ActionRoute. Единица в запросе сопоставляется с {action}, но т.к. у action ограничение на строку, то дальше запрос сопоставляется с роутом DefaultApi

Где ошибка?

Comment: У вас в контроллере 2 метода. Один назван `Get`, второй помечен аттрибутом `[HttpGet]` с роутом по умолчанию. Как asp.net поймет, что вызвать?

Comment: @tym32167 а почему в первом случае он срабатывает? (спрашиваю любопытства ради).

Comment: потому что в первом вы явно сказали, какое действие вызвать `api/consultants/GgetByEntityId/1`

Comment: Не понимаю, как исправить. Помогите

Comment: что исправить то? Вы же не написали, как оно должно работать

Comment: чтобы работали оба запроса

Comment: ну один метод вы уже умеете вызывать, вызовите второй как `http://localhost:54788/api/consultants/Get/1` - должно отработать

Comment: http://localhost:54788/api/consultants/get/1 - да, так работает
Но согласно REST архитектуре так же более правильно? 
http://localhost:54788/api/consultants/1
Хотелось бы, чтобы именно так работало

Comment: ну отлично, значит проблема решена )

Comment: Согласно REST у вас метода `GgetByEntityId` быть не должно

Comment: Но у меня будут методы типа GetByCategoryId - как тогда быть?

Comment: измените у вашего метода `GgetByEntityId` аттрибут с `[HttpGet]` на `[HttpGet("api/consultants/GgetByEntityId/{id}")]`

Comment: `методы типа GetByCategoryId` я бы сделал `api/category/{mycategory}/product` - для списка продуктов по категории

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Сейчас работает. Но так и не понял почему настройка маршрутов не соответствует запросам. Или так нельзя настроить через MapHttpRoute как я хочу? И вообще есть ли ограничения на настройку роутов или я могу их сделать такими, какими хочу?

Comment: Вы можете настроить маршруты практически так, как хотите. Чтобы понять, как это сделать, мне бы пришлось вам всю справку пересказывать. Мой совет - ознакомьтесь с документацией и всё станет намного понятней

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Настройка роутинга web api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/863901/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b0-web-api)